# SharePoint 2013 Client People Picker

Tags: 2013

I have an issue - I enter correct email of user to client people picker, but I do not see any suggestion to choose user. If I copy and past the same email, I see the error message - there are several users with the same email. After this I can resolve what user should be     chosen.

How can I add the same behavior when I enter email manually or validate/resolve user name in people picker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email address is the UNIQUE identifier for AD when you use EnsureUser (Which all of internal sharepoint does)

This means it is have resolution conflicts, alter this by stepping through the users and giving unique even bogus email addresses.

Comment: it's not true for user profile.

Comment: It's still how ensure user works, if the user has an email address it is used to resolve the user, a non unique email causes conflicts.

Comment: but why it can be solved if I copy and past this email???

Comment: people picker gives suggestions, the default suggestion is what you copy after the attempted resolve of the login (it can sometimes be wrong)

Comment: Is it possible to resolve email on some button click through Java Script? Make the same behavior of control as "copy and pust" case?

Comment: The copy and paste case is returning [0] from the matched results, it isnt's safe to use. You are better off making a mapping of multiple new emails up for users even if they are all collected under a single email address by the exchange server. user@site.com user1@site.com -> collector@site.com but sp/ad see different unique emails.

Comment: Could you give me some helpful links for me where I can get more details?

Comment: Get ILSpy and look at EnsureUser so you can understand the process better. Afaik it has been discussed on here before but can't find the link, the code is pretty straight forward on how things are resolved.

Answer (score -1):

You should not have more than one user with the same email...this should be impossible as that's what you use to login.

Comment: SharePoint uses claims authentication, thus it's possible.

Comment: Sorry i thought you were using AD with SP which means emails need to be unique